Understanding custom callback group implementation / why do I need a timer to implement time-based logic?
I'm trying to adjust this example for a throttled callback group: https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/humble/rclpy/executors/examples_rclpy_executors/custom_callback_group.py
While adjusting the code, I stumpled accross unexpected behavior. I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.
I was trying to implement time throttling without creating a timer for the callback group. That is, measure the elapsed time since the last call, and allow execution, if it's greater than a threshold. This is the code:
class ThrottledCallbackGroup(CallbackGroup):
    def __init__(self, node):
        super().__init__()
        # measure time since last execution with node clock
        self.clock = node.get_clock()
        self._last_execution_time = 0.0
        self.min_period = 1.0

    def can_execute(self, entity):
        now = self.clock.now().nanoseconds * 1e-9
        elapsed = now - self._last_execution_time
        # allow execution if elapsed time is greater than threshold
        can_execute = elapsed > self.min_period
        print(f"can execute: {can_execute}")
        return can_execute

    def beginning_execution(self, entity):
        now = self.clock.now().nanoseconds * 1e-9
        elapsed = now - self._last_execution_time
        can_execute = elapsed > self.min_period
        print(f"begin execution: {can_execute}")
        if can_execute:
            # update time of execution
            self._last_execution_time = now
            return True
        return False

    def ending_execution(self, entity):
        pass

When I run with this, the first callback will go through, but then it will block indefinitely:
$ python3 test.py
can execute: True
can execute: True
can execute: True
begin execution: True
[INFO] [1723547704.986021978] [intermittent_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 0"
can execute: False
can execute: False

When I implement this with a timer, that resets a flag after a duration (similar to the provided example), this seems to work:
class ThrottledCallbackGroup(CallbackGroup):
    def __init__(self, node):
        super().__init__()
        # no waiting time required before first run
        self._can_execute = True
        self.min_period = 1.0
        self.timer = node.create_timer(self.min_period, self.timer_callback)
        # start timer only after first callback execution
        self.timer.cancel()

    def can_execute(self, entity):
        print(f"can execute: {self._can_execute}")
        return self._can_execute

    def beginning_execution(self, entity):
        print(f"begin execution: {self._can_execute}")
        if self._can_execute:
            self._can_execute = False
            # restart timer to reset flag after min period
            self.timer.reset()
            return True
        return False

    def ending_execution(self, entity):
        pass

    def timer_callback(self):
        self._can_execute = True
        # wait for next execution to refill
        self.timer.cancel()

The output is:
$ python3 test.py
can execute: True
can execute: True
can execute: True
begin execution: True
[INFO] [1723548220.175310204] [intermittent_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 0"
can execute: False
can execute: False
can execute: True
can execute: True
begin execution: True
[INFO] [1723548221.153955207] [intermittent_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 1"
can execute: False
can execute: False
can execute: True
can execute: True
begin execution: True
[INFO] [1723548222.155249731] [intermittent_talker]: Publishing: "Hello World: 2"
can execute: False
can execute: False
...

Specific questions:

Why do I need the timer? Why does it deadlock with just the clock?
Why doesn't can_execute() seem to be called with the frequency of the node's timer, which would be (10 Hz)?
I've seen the example adds a lock in beginning_execution(). Is this just to prevent race conditions with its associated timer, or is it required to protect the logic in case a multi-threaded executor is used, too?
Does can_execute() need to be protected, too (in case the logic there becomes non-trivial)?

